# How to throw valid service SOAP response instead of very ambiguous Server 500 error from SOAP handler

Tags: java, web-services, soaphandler

I am sending SOAPException from my SOAP handler class (Java class) when ever there is a unauthorized user, but in my client it is giving 500 Internal Server Error.

Can any body help me how to throw specific code instead of 500.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That means you are facing some exception in your code.

Comment: Actually, I am only throwing "SOAPFaultException" when ever unauthorized user try to access the webservice.

In my handler class I have overrided the "handleMessage" method. this method returns either true or false.

Guide me how to return proper messge from my handler class to webservice client if he is unauthorized.